# Building an array from ajax JSON response

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, api

I need to build an array from a returned JSON object using jQuery. This would be alot easier if there were a common naming convention or sub-level for these data keys, I know there's a better way to do it but my jQuery is a little rusty. Thanks!

JSON

```
{
"Service": true,
"ZipCode": "02865",
"City": "Lincoln",
"State": "RI",
"plumbing": true,
"electric": true,
"septic": true,
"excavation": true,
"draincleaning": true,
"heating": true,
"cooling": true,
"waterquality": true,
"commercial": true
}
```

jQuery

```
if (response.hasOwnProperty("plumbing")){
  services.push("Plumbing");
}
if (response.hasOwnProperty("electric")){
  services.push("Electric");
}
if (response.hasOwnProperty("septic")){
  services.push("Septic");
}
if (response.hasOwnProperty("excavation")){
  services.push("Excavation");
}
if (response.hasOwnProperty("draincleaning")){
  services.push("Drain Cleaning");
}
if (response.hasOwnProperty("heating")){
  services.push("Heating");
}
if (response.hasOwnProperty("cooling")){
  services.push("Cooling");
}
if (response.hasOwnProperty("waterquality")){
  services.push("Water Quality");
}
if (response.hasOwnProperty("commercial")){
  services.push("Commercial");
}
```

Gives me

```
["Plumbing", "Electric", "Septic", "Excavation", "Drain Cleaning", "Heating", "Cooling", "Water Quality", "Commercial"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the names and use `reduce` to loop thru and check if key exist on the name variable.

```js
//List the names on an object. eg use key waterquality for "Water Quality"
let name = {"plumbing": "Plumbing","electric": "Electric","septic": "Septic","excavation": "Excavation","draincleaning": "Drain Cleaning","heating": "Heating","cooling": "Cooling","waterquality": "Water Quality","commercial": "Commercial"}

//Your object
let obj = {"Service": true,"ZipCode": "02865","City": "Lincoln","State": "RI","plumbing": true,"electric": true,"septic": true,"excavation": true,"draincleaning": true,"heating": true,"cooling": true,"waterquality": true,"commercial": true}

let services = Object.keys(obj).reduce((c, v) => {
  if (name[v]) c.push(name[v]);
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(services);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i in jsonData){
    services.push(i)
}
```

Or you can also do:

```
services = Object.keys(jsonData)
```

Comment: Note that not all keys are shown, eg. `Service`, and their final values are different, eg. `draincleaning` becomes `Drain Cleaning`

Comment: True. Then for the ones he wants to rename, he can check for them with an if statement in the for loop method i listed above. Not sure of a better way other than that.